# wordpress contact form 7 plugin returns js error on console

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

wordpress contact form 7 plugin returns js error on console.
this is the contact form . the error is on auto genarated code by
 the plugin itself

```
 <div class="row">

<div class="col-xs-12  col-sm-4">

[text* your-name class:wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text placeholder "Your Name"] 

[email* your-email class:wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-email placeholder "E-mail address" ] 

[text your-subject class:wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text placeholder "Subject"]

</div>

<div class="col-xs-12  col-sm-8">

[textarea your-message class:wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-textarea class:txt placeholder "Message"] 

[submit class:wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit class:btn class:btn-primary "SEND MESSAGE" ]

  </div>

 </div>
```

Comment: could you add the error?

Comment: TypeError: $(...).tooltip is not a function
http://localhost/wp_emerge/wp-content/themes/emerge/js/main.js
Line 15

Comment: TypeError: this.ajaxForm is not a function
http://localhost/wp_emerge/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/js/scripts.js?ver=4.3.1
Line 12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixed all the trouble.. just put this one after the header parameter..

```
$email = mail(get_option("admin_email"),trim($_POST[your_subject]),stripslashes(trim($_POST[your_message])),$headers, "-fsender@domain.com");
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your error, it clearly states that you have not included the tooltip js file into your page and without including it, you cannot call the function.

include the `tooltip.js` in your html and then the error would go away

for the error on the `ajaxForm` error I found the following solution.

[get the following file from the url](https://github.com/alchapone/ajaxform/blob/master/ajaxform.js)

add the following code to your function.php file

```
function theme_name_scripts() {
   wp_enqueue_script( 'ajaxform', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/ajaxform.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts' );
```

since you are getting the error with contact form 7 the user has posted a solution too. go to the solution provided by `JabariHolder`

[wordpress solution for contactform 7 error](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/undefined-function-ajaxform)

The following is to enque a script onto your website. edit it to get tooltip.js and add it to function.php file

```
wp_register_script('html5blankscripts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/scripts.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0'); // Custom scripts
wp_enqueue_script('html5blankscripts'); // Enqueue it!
```

Comment: that fixed the contact form7 error but there is still error in TypeError: $(...).tooltip is not a function
http://localhost/wp_emerge/wp-content/themes/emerge/js/main.js
Line 15

Comment: Didi you enque the tooltip.js script onto your function php?

Comment: there is no such file tooltip.js .  the whole site is working if i deactivate the cotact form 7 plugin

Comment: I guess there is a plugin missing in either in your contact form plugin or in your website. Best thing is to enque the plugin and see whether it works.

Comment: fix this header file for me    $headers = "From: ".trim($_POST[your_name])." <".trim($_POST[your_email]).">\r\nReply-To:".trim($_POST[your_email]) ;

Comment: this thing is causing all the trouble .. mailed-by: admiral.websitewelcome.com it cannot be changed via headers... Why is this message in Spam? We've found that lots of messages from admiral.websitewelcome.com are spam.

Answer (score 0):

If any one is getting error mentioned by user5549553

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.ajaxForm is not a function
    at a.fn.init.$.fn.wpcf7InitForm (scripts.js?ver=5.1.3:14)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (scripts.js?ver=5.1.3:10)
    at i (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at HTMLDocument.K (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
```

and you have updated to contact-form-7 to ver5.1.3. It may be because of the *wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/js/scripts.js?ver=5.1.3* file getting served from CDN.

In my case I was using the *W3 Total Cache* plugin. Once I removed this file from the CDN using the *Rejected files:* setting the error was gone.