# php contact form sends the mail to spam

Tags: php, wordpress

php contact form sends the mail to spam instead of inbox.

using php with wordpress , tried using contact form 7 but

conflict with bootstrap js made me go back to the core php.

help this form to reach the admin inbox

```
<?php

 if ($_POST[sent]) {
$error = "";
if (!trim($_POST[your_name])) {
    $error .= "<p>Please enter your name</p>";
}
if (!filter_var(trim($_POST[your_email]), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $error .= "<p>Please enter a valid email address</p>";
}
if (!trim($_POST[your_message])) {
    $error .= "<p>Please enter a message</p>";
}
if (!$error) {
    //trim($_POST[your_name])." sent you a message from ".get_option("blogname")." website "." on subject "

    $email = mail(get_option("admin_email"), trim($_POST[your_subject]), stripslashes(trim($_POST[your_message])), "From: " . trim($_POST[your_name]) . " <" . trim($_POST[your_email]) . ">\r\nReply-To:" . trim($_POST[your_email]));
}
}
 ?>

 <?php get_header(); ?>


   <!--contact_part-->

<div class="main-title" style="background-color: #f2f2f2; ">
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="main-title__primary">Contact Us</h1>

        <h3 class="main-title__secondary">WE ARE WAITING YOU TO GET IN TOUCH WITH US</h3>
    </div>
</div>


  <div class="master-container">


<div class="map">

    <div style="text-decoration:none; overflow:hidden; height:350px; width:100%; max-width:100%;">
        <div id="embed-map-display" style="height:100%; width:100%;max-width:100%;">
            <iframe style="height:100%;width:100%;border:0;" frameborder="0"
                    src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=qather+dhoha&key=AIzaSyAN0om9mFmy1QN6Wf54tXAowK4eT0ZUPrU"></iframe>
        </div>
        <a class="embed-map-html" href="https://www.treat-lice.com/head-lice-treatment-101/"
           id="authorize-map-data">Head lice treatment 101</a>
        <style>#embed-map-display .text-marker {
                max-width: none !important;
                background: none !important;
            }

            img {
                max-width: none
            }</style>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="spacer-big"></div>


<div role="main" class="hentry container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="panel panel-grid widget widget_text panel-last-child">
                <h3 class="widget-title">Contact Us</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="textwidget panel widget">
                <span class="icon-container"><span class="fa fa-home"></span></span> <b>Emerge trading & contracting
                    WLL</b><br>
                <?= get_template_option_values('your_place'); ?><br>
                <?= get_template_option_values('your_place_address'); ?><br><br>
                <span class="icon-container"><span class="fa fa-phone"></span></span> <b>
                    <?= get_template_option_values('cc_email_address'); ?>
                    ,<?= get_template_option_values('cc_contact_numbers'); ?></b><br>

                <span class="icon-container"><span class="fa fa-envelope"></span></span><a
                    href="mailto:info@example.com"><?= get_template_option_values('mail-id'); ?></a>
                <br><br>
                <span class="icon-container"><span class="fa fa-home"></span></span>
                <b><?= get_template_option_values('working_time'); ?></b><br>
                <?= get_template_option_values('working_days'); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="panel widget widget_pt_social_icons panel-last-child">
                <a target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/<?= get_template_option_values('facebook_id'); ?>"
                   class="social-icons__link"><i class="fa  fa-facebook"></i></a>
                <a target="_blank" href="http://www.twitter.com/<?= get_template_option_values('twitter_id'); ?>"
                   class="social-icons__link"><i class="fa  fa-twitter"></i></a>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div lang="en-US" dir="ltr" id="wpcf7-f5-o1" class="wpcf7">


                <div id="container">
                    <div id="content" role="main">
                        <?php if (have_posts()) while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                            <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
                                <!--<h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>-->
                                <div class="entry-content">
                                    <?php if ($email) { ?>
                                        <p><strong>Message succesfully sent. We will get back to you
                                                shortly.</strong></p>
                                    <?php } else {
                                        if ($error) { ?>
                                            <p><strong>Your messange has not been sent</strong><p>
                                            <?php echo $error; ?>
                                        <?php } else {
                                            the_content();
                                        } ?>


                                        <form novalidate class="wpcf7-form" action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"
                                              id="contact_me" method="post">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="sent" id="sent" value="1"/>

                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-xs-12  col-sm-4">
                                <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-name">
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Your Name" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text"
                                           size="40" value="" name="your_name" id="your_name">
                                </span><br>
                                <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-email">
                                    <input type="email" placeholder="E-mail address"
                                           class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-email" size="40" value=""
                                           name="your_email" id="your_email">
                                </span><br>
                                <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-subject">
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Subject" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text"
                                           size="40" value="" name="your_subject" id="your_subject">
                                </span>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-xs-12  col-sm-8">
                                <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-message">
                                    <textarea placeholder="Message" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-textarea"
                                              style="height:220px;" rows="10" cols="40" name="your_message"
                                              id="your_message"></textarea>
                                </span><br>
                                                    <input type="submit" name="send"
                                                           class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit btn btn-primary"
                                                           value="SEND MESSAGE">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </form>


                                    <?php } ?>
                                </div><!-- .entry-content -->
                            </div><!-- #post-## -->
                        <?php endwhile; ?>
                    </div><!-- #content -->
                </div><!-- #container -->
                <!--<?php get_sidebar(); ?>-->

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="spacer-big"></div>
```

Comment: We dont know what type of antyspam you have, so i dont think so, that anyone can help you. Use smtp server with valid email account - it may help you. Anty spam can also check of message, ip, so there is many possibilities

Comment: This has nothing to do with your code as such. It's a matter of the receiver's provider (gmail, yahoo and so on) whether they identify your email as spam, using SPF and DKIM and a couple of other things should keep your emails out of the spam folder.

Comment: im just an entry-level web developer .. i have no access to anything more than cpanel.  help me fix this one .     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33889808/

Answer (score 0):

fixed all the trouble.. just put this one after the header parameter..

```
$email = mail(get_option("admin_email"),trim($_POST[your_subject]),stripslashes(trim($_POST[your_message])),$headers, "-fsender@domain.com");
```